How to config query timeout default for all query?
I am working with GORM in my Go application and I need to set a default query timeout for all queries. Currently, I have individual queries where I set the timeout explicitly, But I want to avoid repetitive code and set a default timeout that applies to all queries executed through GORM. Such as:
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(),
    config.DB_TIMEOUT)
defer cancel()
res := tx.WithContext(ctx).Model(&Stock{}).Update(myMap)

Is there a way to configure a default query timeout for GORM queries globally, so that I don't have to specify it for each query individually?

Wrap the execution creating a context with timeout and Bob‘s your uncle.

Add timeout to dsn, e.g.
dsn := "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname? loc=Local&timeout=10s"
gorm also supports other settings
sqlDB, _ := db.DB()
sqlDB.SetMaxIdleConns(m.maxIdleConn)
sqlDB.SetMaxOpenConns(m.maxOpenConn)
sqlDB.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)


I using postgresql. Have some query need using timeout specific such as: 10s, 20s. How to your solution can resolve it?

This answer is mainly to solve your global configuration , if there is a specific query, it is better to solve it through WithTimeout.
